# Grouping and Removing duplicates except one column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables

1. Speakers
2. Sessions
3. Events

### Events_tbl

```
id  event_name
--- -----------
1   event1
2   event2
3   event3
```

### Speakers_tbl

```
id  name
--- ----
1   john
2   smith
3   sooraj
```

### Sessions_tbl

```
id      name        speaker_id     event_id
----    ----        --------       ------
1       session1    1              1
2       session2    2              1
3.      session3    1              2
4.      session1    1              3
5.      session2    3              3
```

My need to get the result like this....

```
id  speakername     event_name
--- ------------    -----------
1   john            event1, event2, event3
2   smith           event1
3.  sooraj          event3
```

How to get this in MYSQL...?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` and `group by`:

```
select sp.id, sp.name, group_concat(e.event_name separator ', ')
from speakers sp left join
     sessions s
     on sp.speaker_id = s.id left join
     events e
     on sp.event_id = e.id
group by sp.id, sp.name;
```

If the event name can repeat for a given speaker, you can use:

```
group_concat(distinct e.event_name separator ', ')
```

Comment: but the e.event_name also repeating, when a speaker has 2 or more sessions in a event.

Comment: yeah bro... i fixed that issue with distinct function.